# How to get total days of each month in a leap year

Tags: php

I am trying to create a script function which gets total days of each month of a year.
My idea is create a report of the last 12 months and we have probability to get leap year and my calculation does not cover this.
I tried to create a code which maps all of months except leap year when february has 29 days.

Here my code:

```
public function checkMes(){

    // ----------------------------------- Verificar se o mes tem 30 ou 31  ou 28 dias  -------------
    $month = array();
    for ($i = -10; $i < 0; $i++)
    {
        $check_month = date('m');

        if($check_month == '01' || $check_month == '03' || $check_month == '05' || $check_month == '07' || $check_month == '08' || $check_month == '10' || $check_month == '12')
        {
            $month[] = date('m/Y',strtotime('+'.$i.' months + 1 days'));

        }elseif($check_month == '02'){
             $month[] = date('m/Y',strtotime('+'.$i.' months - 2 days'));

        }else{
            $month[] = date('m/Y',strtotime('+'.$i.' months')); 

        }
    }
    return $month;
}
```

Can  anyone help me with this?

[UPDATE]

I need to know if february has 29 or 28 since my data needs to be calculated and reported.
If I have an sale in Feb 29th, I need to consider it in my report, not until Feb 28th

Comment: `date('L');` tells you if it's a leap year.

Comment: What is your expected result?

Comment: you can use `day 0` of a month to get the last day of the previous month, e.g. `March 0th, 2014` is really `Feb 28th, 2014`.

Comment: I'm expecting to build a report with 12 months that have passed.
For example: I need to create a report from  december, 2011 to november 2012, since 2012 is leap year or not.

Comment: You asked for total days of each month of a year. But your code returns month/year ????

Comment: He try to say we need to identify if february has 28 or 29 days

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is easy one.
Create a function which calculates if the current year is divisible by 4 or 400 and not divisible by 100.

Let me clarify what I mean with some script code:

Firts, create a small function to get the current year and calculate it. It wseems like this one:

```
public function leap($ano)
{       
    $leap = false;    

    if ( (($ano%4) == 0 && ($ano%100) != 0) || ($ano%400) == 0 )    
    {       
        $leap = true;    
    }     
    return $leap;
}
```

Now you need to modify your current function and add the following code that I commented:

```
public function checkMes(){
    $ano = date('Y'); //add this line
    $this->leap($ano); // add this line

    // ----------------------------------- Verificar se o mes tem 30 ou 31  ou 28 dias  -------------
    $month = array();
    for ($i = -10; $i < 0; $i++)
    {
        $check_month = date('m');

        if($check_month == '01' || $check_month == '03' || $check_month == '05' || $check_month == '07' || $check_month == '08' || $check_month         == '10' || $check_month == '12')
        {
            $month[] = date('m/Y',strtotime('+'.$i.' months + 1 days'));

        }elseif($check_month == '02'){

            if(isset($leap)){  //add this line
                $month[] = date('m/Y',strtotime('+'.$i.' months - 1 days'));   //add this line

            }else{   //add this line
                $month[] = date('m/Y',strtotime('+'.$i.' months - 2 days'));   //add this line

            }   //add this line

        }else{
            $month[] = date('m/Y',strtotime('+'.$i.' months')); 

        }
    }
    return $month;
}
```

Hope It helps you.

Comment: Thanks @bcesars. This really was helpful and works perfectly in my code.

Answer (score 1):

`date('t')` gives you the number of days in a given month.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php

So instead of the if-elseif-else block, you could just do:

```
$month[] = date('m/Y',strtotime('+'.date('t').' days'));
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `date("t")`:

```
<?php
  $number_of_days_in_month = date('t');
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

I know to solve it in PHP, your conditions are wrong:

Try this:

```
$arr = array(1944, 2011, 2012, 2013, 2014, 1986, 1800, 1900, 2000, 2056);

    function leapYear($year){
        if(($year % 4) == 0 && ($year % 100) != 0){
            return true;
        }
        else{
            return false;
        }
    }

    for($i = 0; $i < count($arr) ; $i++){
        $r = leapYear($arr[$i]);

        if($r){
            echo 'Lepo year: ' . $arr[$i] . '<br>';
        }else{
            echo 'Not Leap year: ' . $arr[$i] . '<br>';
        }

    }
```